# Union of layout-compatible types

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, unions, standard-layout

Look at this code:

```
struct A {
    short s;
    int i;
};
struct B {
    short s;
    int i;
};

union U {
    A a;
    B b;
};

int fn() {
    U u;
    u.a.i = 1;
    return u.b.i;
}
```

Is it guaranteed that `fn()` returns `1`?

Note: this is a follow-up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041630/whats-the-purpose-of-layout-compatible-types).

Answer (score 12):

Yes, this is defined behavior.  First lets see what the standard has to say about `A` and `B`.  [[class.prop]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class#prop-3) has

> A class S is a standard-layout class if it:
>
> - has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
> - has no virtual functions and no virtual base classes,
> - has the same access control for all non-static data members,
> - has no non-standard-layout base classes,
> - has at most one base class subobject of any given type,
> - has all non-static data members and bit-fields in the class and its base classes first declared in the same class, and
> - [...] (nothing said here has any bearing in this case)

So `A` and `B` are both standard layout types.  If we look at [[class.mem]/23](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class#mem-23)

> Two standard-layout struct types are layout-compatible classes if their common initial sequence comprises all members and bit-fields of both classes ([basic.types]).

and [[class.mem]/22](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.mem#22)

> The common initial sequence of two standard-layout struct types is the longest sequence of non-static data members and bit-fields in declaration order, starting with the first such entity in each of the structs, such that corresponding entities have layout-compatible types, either both entities are declared with the no_­unique_­address attribute ([dcl.attr.nouniqueaddr]) or neither is, and either both entities are bit-fields with the same width or neither is a bit-field.

and [[class.mem]/25](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.mem#25)

> In a standard-layout union with an active member of struct type T1, it is permitted to read a non-static data member m of another union member of struct type T2 provided m is part of the common initial sequence of T1 and T2; the behavior is as if the corresponding member of T1 were nominated. [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct T1 { int a, b; };
> struct T2 { int c; double d; };
> union U { T1 t1; T2 t2; };
> int f() {
>   U u = { { 1, 2 } };   // active member is t1
>   return u.t2.c;        // OK, as if u.t1.a were nominated
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ] [ Note: Reading a volatile object through a glvalue of non-volatile type has undefined behavior ([dcl.type.cv]). — end note ]

Then we have that the classes have the same common initial sequence, are laid out the same, and accessing the same member of the non-active type is treated as if accessing that member of the active type.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `offsetof` of `A::i` and `B::i` are the same? The text just says "OK, ... nominated". Or what guarantees that 1 will be returned? It seems logical of course, I just fail to see the guarantee of it. Even in the presence of common initial sequence. I don't see guaranteed that the common initial sequence laid out the same. Or is it guaranteed somewhere?

Comment: @geza It is in the text above the code: *the behavior is as if the corresponding member of T1 were nominated.*

Comment: @geza Let me add a little more to show the classes have to be laid out the same

Comment: @NathanOliver does `u` has an active member in the OP question?

Comment: @Jans From my reading `u.a.i = 1;` makes it active: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.union#5

Comment: @geza I've updated the answer.  Let me know if anything is still unclear to you.

Comment: @NathanOliver: thank for the answer! This is still not clear for me: "Then we have that the classes have the same initial common sequence, are laided out the same". Why? Where is it written that a common initial sequence is laid out the same?

Comment: @geza [class.mem]/23: *Two standard-layout struct types are layout-compatible classes if their common initial sequence comprises all members and bit-fields of both classes ([basic.types]).*

Comment: @NathanOliver: where does this statement say this?

Comment: @geza They are *layout-compatible* so they are laid out the same, at least for the initial common sequence.

Comment: So, do you say that the word *layout-compatible* implies this? I'm not sure that I agree with this. Usually, this kind of things specified explicitly.

Comment: @geza I think I need to add [\[basic.types\]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.types#11):Two types cv1 T1 and cv2 T2 are layout-compatible types if T1 and T2 are the same type, layout-compatible enumerations, or layout-compatible standard-layout class types.  Does that make it make more sense for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I don't see that why *layout-compatible* mean "members of layout-compatible types are laid out the same". Of course, it is the only sane behavior, but it still not specified this way. At least, I don't see where it is specified like this.

Comment: @NathanOliver: If a compiler meaningfully upholds the Common Initial Sequence guarantee, taking the address of `someUnion.struct1.memberX` should yield a pointer that can be used to view the live state of someUnion.struct2.memberX` if both struct members are matching parts of a Common Initial Sequence.  The easiest way to guarantee that would be to place the fields at matching offsets, though I don't know if the Standard would forbid an implementation from using some other weird and wacky means instead.