# How to cast one struct to another type with identical members?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

If I'm given a struct variable like:

```
struct Quaternion {
    float    x;
    float    y;
    float    z;
    float    w;
}
```

But I need to call a function expecting a

```
struct Vector {
    float    x;
    float    y;
    float    z;
    float    w;
}
```

Is there a way in C++ to cast a variable of type Quaternion to type Vector?

Comment: Well, yes, you could cast, but as soon as the order of the members would change it would break. Can't you use struct inheritance so a Quaternion inherits of a Vector ?

Comment: @Michoumichmich well the types are not my making. They are from 2 different libraries I am using.

Comment: @cecil: Would it be terrible to just write a trivial converting function? Make it inline, and it's entirely possible the compiler will figure it out and not actually do any work in cases where mutation isn't a possibility (testing required to confirm). As largest_prime's answer notes, you could template it to work on arbitrary types if conversions in both directions are desired (especially easy in this case, since the types involved all have the same names for attributes).

Comment: Look at `User-defined conversions` and maybe declare such a method friend of struct Quaternion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a converting constructor:

```
struct Quaternion {
    float    x;
    float    y;
    float    z;
    float    w;
    explicit Quaternion(const Vector& vec) : x(vec.x),y(vec.y),z(vec.z),w(vec.w) {}    
}
```

And similar for the other way.

In case you are looking for a way that does not require to copy the members, then I am not aware of a portable way to do that, and members having the same name does not help for that.

On the other hand, having same named members helps to write generic code like this:

```
 template <typename T>
 void foo(const T& t) {
     std::cout << t.x << t.y << t.z << t.w;
 }
```

You can call this with either a `Quaternion` or a `Vector` without needing to convert between them.

In case you cannot modify any existing code (not the structs nor the function you want to call), you can write a simple function to do the conversion (as suggested by ShadowRanger in a comment):

```
Vector Quat2Vect(const Quaternion& q) {
    return {q.x,q.y,q.z,q.w};
}
```

Comment: You might want to make that constructor `explicit` so it doesn't cast implicitly.

Comment: OK. In the case a Vector* was needed would it be safe to pass in (Vector*)(&quaternion)  ?

Comment: @cecil: Officially, by the standard, no (it would be an aliasing violation I believe, and if they're not POD types, you could easily have incompatible layouts). In practice, on most compilers, sure, it would *probably* work. Probably...

Comment: @cecil no just because two structs have same members, does not mean that you are guaranteed that they have same memory layout. It is to be expected, but not legal according to the standard. Copying is the only way afaik

Comment: If works but it's not safe, write a copy constructor that will probably be optimised out to your pointer aliasing

Comment: If one of your structs, has a different alignement, the cast doesn't work

Comment: @cecil look eg here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55068593/is-it-safe-to-assertsizeofa-sizeofb-when-a-and-b-are-the-same. Its a question of mine about a related issue. Thing is: You are not even guaranteed that `sizeof(Vector) == sizeof(Quaternion)` (even though it would be strange to encounter a difference)

Comment: OK. I won't chance it and will write a conversion. Thank you again.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I don't think that answer is correct. There is a concept of "layout compatible" defined in the standard. Layout-compatible structs still can't be cast from one type to the other because of aliasing rules, but it *is* permissible to `memcpy` between them. That wouldn't be possible if two identically defined structs could end up with different sizes.

Comment: @JimOldfield I was just quotimg the answer. I you object, you should write another answer

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Done: I have added an answer to this question and to the one you linked to.

Answer (score 3):

If, as you said in a comment, you can't change to the two types, you could possibly "solve" the problem by using yet another type:

```
struct MyVector {
    float    x;
    float    y;
    float    z;
    float    w;
    operator Quaternion() { return Quaternion{x, y, z, w}; }
    operator Vector() { return Vector{x, y, z, w}; }
};
```

**My advice**: It's probably better to pick one or the other as the main type in your code and use a separate conversion function.

What I think you're hoping for, given that you specifically asked about "cast", is to use a cast to go from one to the other.

```
Vector v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Quaternion* q = reinterpret_cast<Quaternion*>(&v);
do_something_with_quart(*q);  // Could modify v if pass by reference
```

Strictly speaking, this is undefined behaviour, although it is overwhelmingly likely to work in practice, but I still wouldn't recommend it. If you're really desparate to do something cast like, it's legal to use `memcpy` so long as the member variables are the same type in the same order (and there are no virtual methods):

```
Vector v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Quaternion q;
memcpy(&q, &v, sizeof(v));
do_something_with_quart(q);
memcpy(&v, &q, sizeof(v));  // Copy back any change
```

Although the language and documentation describes `memcpy` as a copying function, it has certain magical properties that often in practice make it identical to the previous block of code. But I would also strongly advise against this. I mean, yuck! Just look at it!!

Answer (score 3):

This is just an addition to [largest_prime_is_463035818's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65670895) to point out that the members don't have to have the same name in order to write a generic function to use them. So long as there are an equal number of members, all are publicly accessible, and they have the same types, you can decompose objects with a structured-binding and use that.

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T& t) {
    auto const & [x, y, z, w] = t;  
    std::cout << x << y << z << w;
}
```