# how do I use type punning, without having to use memcpy

Tags: c++, type-punning

So, I hav a class that has a variable `alignas(void*) bool failed` inside.
That `failed` variable contains an address.

```
    auto getFailed() {
        unsigned long long adress;
        memcpy(&adress, &(this->failed), sizeof(void*));
        return ((BaseA*)(void*)(adress))->failed;
    }
```

The above code works well, but I think its kind of ugly to do that memcpy thing

So I tried the following:

```
    auto getFailed() {
        return ((BaseA*)&(this->failed))->failed;
    }
```

In theorie this should work just fine, but it does not.
I am not really sure why, and how to fix it.

Comment: Why is it a `bool`? It just asks for trouble.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of the issue. But if you are intentionally breaking the (aliasing) rules of C++ then no wonder it doesn't work, the rules are not there just to make the Standard longer. The fix is to either use memcpy, or do not store `void*` inside `bool` in the first place, why would you?

Comment: [std::bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast)

Comment: why "ugly" ? This is purely subjective. If it works it is beautiful, no?

Comment: My understanding is that, if you don't have bitcast (see answer below), the key is to write a memcpy and code around it that is simple enough so the compiler can see through that the operation is trivial. Seeing the generated code is useful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot really type-pun a `bool` into an `unsigned long long` via `memcpy` (unless they have the same size). Putting `alignas(void*)` on a `bool` doesn't solve this, because you're reading bytes that are past its object representation. It is memory-safe to do because of padding in the surrounding `struct`, but it's still undefined behavior in C++.

See also: [Why does std::memcpy (as an alternative to type-punning) not cause undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58209852/5740428) tl; dr: the only thing you can do with `std::memcpy` is copy values between two objects of the same type. Anything beyond that is a compiler extension.

On a side note, it would be much better to use `std::uintptr_t` instead of `unsigned long long`, because it is guaranteed to have the same size as `void*`.

#### Solution with `std::bit_cast`

Since C++20, there is a function that does this `memcpy` step for you:

```cpp
auto getFailed() {
    return std::bit_cast<std::uintptr_t>(this->failed);
}
```

However, you cannot use it, because it requires `sizeof(this->failed) == sizeof(std::uintptr_t)`.
You would have to put your `bool` into a wrapper `struct` with the same size as `unsigned long long` instead of padding it via `alignas`:

```cpp
struct {
    // important: Don't use alignas directly, because void* could have no alignment
    //            requirements despite being 8 bytes in size.
    //            In that case, we would have no padding.
    alignas(sizeof(void*)) bool value;
} failed;
```

However, this is still technically UB, because bit-casting padding bits is UB in most cases. You must bit-cast bits which are part of the value representation of an object, so we must add manual paddding:

```cpp
alignas(void*) struct {
    bool value;
    char padding[sizeof(void*) - sizeof(bool)];
} failed;
```

#### Solution with `reinterpret_cast`

```cpp
auto getFailed() {
    // your code, but C-style cast converted to reinterpret_cast
    return reinterpret_cast<BaseA*>(&this->failed)->failed;
}
```

**Don't even consider this, it's undefined behavior.**
It would be a violation of strict aliasing to read a `std::uintptr_t` through a pointer that is actually pointing to `bool`. These two types cannot alias each other.